# How it comes I was able to edit someone else question?

Tags: support, editing

Saw a question and noticed it could use some formatting on code, clicked on 'edit' and did the work. Then it occurred to me that I don't have rep enough for this. Checked the [reputation list](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/privileges) and indeed I would need 2k rep for editing rights.

So is it bugged or did I misunderstand this rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/

Comment: Got it, thanks.